# Same number of occurrences before and after a characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to implements a regular expression to validate a code composed by two number that must have always the same length. These are some example of the possible values:

- 1 6
- 12 67
- 123 678
- 1234 6789
- 12345 67890

I have a limit of 5 digit so the only solution that I found working is this:

```
^(
   ([0-9][ ][0-9])|
   ([0-9]{2}[ ][0-9]{2}) |
   ([0-9]{3}[ ][0-9]{3}) |
   ([0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}) |
   ([0-9]{5}[ ][0-9]{5})
)$
```

Any suggestion or alternatives are accepted. After a day of thinking about, this solution is the only way to perform this check, but I know is greedy.

Comment: What is the regex flavor, just in case?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: In .NET, you could use [`^(?<o>\d){1,5} (?<-o>\d){1,5}(?(o)(?!))$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3co%3e%5cd)%7b1%2c5%7d+(%3f%3c-o%3e%5cd)%7b1%2c5%7d(%3f(o)(%3f!))%5cr%3f%24&i=1+6%0d%0a12+67%0d%0a123+678%0d%0a1234+6789%0d%0a12345+67890%0d%0a11+2%0d%0a1+22%0d%0a123456+123456&o=m)

Comment: However, the enumeration of the possible 5 variations works 23% quicker.

Comment: .NET but I wanted to check if there's no other solution with regex.
The solution of @WiktorStribiżew sound new to me. I'll check it later.

Comment: None of other regex flavors does not support stack for capture groups that you can track. If you know one, please let know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, as you are using this regex flavor, you may leverage [**balancing constructs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition):

```
^(?<o>\d){1,5} (?<-o>\d){1,5}(?(o)(?!))$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Co%3E%5Cd)%7B1%2C5%7D%20(%3F%3C-o%3E%5Cd)%7B1%2C5%7D(%3F(o)(%3F!))%5Cr%3F%24&i=1%206%0D%0A12%2067%0D%0A123%20678%0D%0A1234%206789%0D%0A12345%2067890%0D%0A11%202%0D%0A1%2022%0D%0A123456%20123456&o=m)

Also, see [**Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html).

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?<o>\d){1,5}` - matches 1 to 5 digits capturing each of them one by one into `o` group adding up to the `Captures` stack with each match
- - space (put into a character class if you use `RegexOptions.IngorePatternWhitespace` flag)
- `(?<-o>\d){1,5}` - 1 to 5 digits each time subtracting a value from the `o` group stack
- `(?(o)(?!))` - a conditional construct that checks the stack of Group `o`. If it is not empty (`(?(o))`), the whole match is failed (with `(?!)` negative lookahead)
- `$` - end of string.

**However, your variation enumeration approach is faster.**